# QR Code generate only getting last result from database table

Tags: php

I'm building a QRCode system using this library https://github.com/tecnickcom/tc-lib-barcode. It's working great, but for some odd reason it's only outputting the last result of the $row["url_link"] in the loop. Let me explain.

I have 3 results inside the "qr_codes" table in the following column url_link results (see below)

https://google.com 
https://yahoo.com 
https://bing.com

It will generate all 3 QRCodes to the browser window but they are all the same QRCodes url links. All 3 QRCodes are https://bing.com

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated

**Here is my code:**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";


// Include the library in your project
require ('vendor/autoload.php');

$barcode = new \Com\Tecnick\Barcode\Barcode();
   
 

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


// Get the links from the qr_codes tables
$sql = "SELECT url_link FROM qr_codes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$dir = "qr-code/";

// Directory to store barcode
if (! is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
}
// data string to encode
$source = $row["url_link"];


// *** Generate qr code *** //

// set properties
$qrcodeObj = $barcode->getBarcodeObj('QRCODE,H', $source, - 16, - 16, 'black', array(
    - 2,
    - 2,
    - 2,
    - 2
))->setBackgroundColor('#FFF');

// generate qrcode
$imageData = $qrcodeObj->getPngData();
$timestamp = time();

//store in the directory
file_put_contents($dir . $timestamp . '.png', $imageData);

 //Output image to the browser
echo '<img src="'.$dir . $timestamp.'.png" width="200px" height="200px">';

// *** Generate qr code *** //


}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Would it be possible that all three QR images have the same file name: `$dir . $timestamp . '.png'`? Using a `$timestamp` doesn't seem a reliable way to make them different.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - that's the other issue. It's only creating one file and placing it into the "qr-code" directory . Shouldn't the while create 3 different files since the num_rows is 3 results?  ? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Maybe all three qr codes are generated within one second, that's why they get the same filename.

Comment: I don't like the `$timestamp` as a differentiating factor between the 3 images. Just imagine what would happen if your code executes extremely fast: They would all get the same timestamp. Better use a counter in this case. So `$counter = 0;` before the while loop, and then in the loop `$counter++;` and use that in the image like this: `$dir . 'image' . $counter . '.png'`

Comment: Thank you both! That does make sense. I will take a look.

Comment: @schmauch you too!

Comment: @code regarding your most recently deleted question, I might recommend that you unconditionally attempt an `UPDATE` query then check if it `affected_rows()`, then if zero affected rows, then `INSERT`.  That seems a clean way of doing it.  Bear in mind, that mysql has its own `date` functions and constants, so you won't need to pass in today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't fixed this yet; all you have to do is rename your  for each item in your loop:

Change this:

echo '`<img src="'.$dir . $timestamp.'.png" width="200px" height="200px">`';

To this:

echo '`<img src="'.$dir . $row['id'].'.png" width="200px" height="200px">`';

The difference is you are renaming each item in the loop, so no item is the same.